# Google Chrome Javascript issue in getting user audio - The AudioContext was not allowed to start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audiocontext

I have this Javascript code which I am using to capture audio input from user when they click on a microphone button. This code works in Mozila Firefox but when I am using it in Google Chrome it does not work and shows this warning/error in console - `The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.`

```
var r = function() {
            var e = {}
              , t = void 0
              , n = getBotConfig()
              , r = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,")
              , o = !1;
            if (!n.isIE()) {
                window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                var i = new AudioContext;
                e.toggleRecording = function(e, t, n, r, s, a, c) {
                    e.classList.contains("recording") ? (e.classList.remove("recording"),
                    o = !1,
                    t.emit("end-recording", {
                        session_id: a,
                        bot_id: c
                    }),
                    document.getElementById("btnToggle").setAttribute("style", "background-color:transparent"),
                    document.getElementsByClassName("fa-microphone")[0] && document.getElementsByClassName("fa-microphone")[0].setAttribute("style", "color:" + s)) : (e.classList.add("recording"),
                    o = !0,
                    t.emit("start-recording", {
                        numChannels: 1,
                        bps: 16,
                        fps: parseInt(i.sampleRate),
                        session_id: a,
                        bot_id: c
                    }),
                    document.getElementById("btnToggle").setAttribute("style", "background-color:" + n),
                    document.getElementsByClassName("fa-microphone")[0] && document.getElementsByClassName("fa-microphone")[0].setAttribute("style", "color:" + r))
                }
                ,
                e.onAudioTTS = function(e) {
                    try {
                        r.pause(),
                        c(e)
                    } catch (t) {
                        c(e)
                    }
                }
                ,
                e.initAudio = function(e, n, r) {
                    console.log("audio initiated"),
                    t = e,
                    navigator.getUserMedia || (navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia),
                    navigator.cancelAnimationFrame || (navigator.cancelAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || navigator.mozCancelAnimationFrame),
                    navigator.requestAnimationFrame || (navigator.requestAnimationFrame = navigator.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || navigator.mozRequestAnimationFrame),
                    navigator.getUserMedia({
                        audio: !0
                    }, a, function(e) {
                        alert("Error getting audio"),
                        console.log(e)
                    })
                }
                ;
                var s = function(e) {
                    var t = i.createChannelSplitter(2)
                      , n = i.createChannelMerger(2);
                    return e.connect(t),
                    t.connect(n, 0, 0),
                    t.connect(n, 0, 1),
                    n
                }
                  , a = function(e) {
                    var n = i.createGain()
                      , r = i.createMediaStreamSource(e)
                      , a = r;
                    a = s(a),
                    a.connect(n);
                    var c = (i.createScriptProcessor || i.createJavaScriptNode).call(i, 1024, 1, 1);
                    c.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
                        if (o) {
                            for (var n = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0), r = new ArrayBuffer(2 * n.length), i = new DataView(r), s = 0, a = 0; s < n.length; s++,
                            a += 2) {
                                var c = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, n[s]));
                                i.setInt16(a, c < 0 ? 32768 * c : 32767 * c, !0)
                            }
                            t.emit("write-audio", r)
                        }
                    }
                    ,
                    n.connect(c),
                    c.connect(i.destination);
                    var u = i.createGain();
                    u.gain.value = 0,
                    n.connect(u),
                    u.connect(i.destination)
                }
                  , c = function(e) {
                    r.src = "data:audio/wav;base64," + e,
                    r.play()
                };
                return e
            }
        };
```

The warning/error is coming at line `var i = new AudioContext;`. It used to work before on Google Chrome browser as well but now it's not working. The description on Google developers page says `resume()` must be used to but I am not sure how and where should I do this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you should be able to call `resume()` somewhere right before you call `play()`. The important thing is to call it within a user action/event - like the click on the microphone button.

> Key Point: If an AudioContext is created prior to the document
>   receiving a user gesture, it will be created in the "suspended" state,
>   and you will need to call resume() after a user gesture is received.

from https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

> It used to work before on Google Chrome browser as well but now it's
>   not working.

The new policy has been enforced recently within a chrome update.

Comment: Is this specific to just chrome? Will calling `resume()` have side effects for other browser engines?

Answer (score 11):

You should call, `getAudioContext().resume();` somewhere.

If your question is related to p5.js when accessing microphone, do this in `setup`

```
function setup() {
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  getAudioContext().resume();
}
```

Or add `touchStarted` function the document. You have to click on the web page to trigger this function.

```
function touchStarted() {
  getAudioContext().resume();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Came across this much later and just wanted to add something for posterity.  The above answers are correct using `getAudioContext().resume()` but this error can also be avoided if the `AudioContext` is created inside `getUserMedia` as such

```
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then((stream) => {
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    // ... rest of code
})
```

In this way, the `AudioContext` will not be put into the suspended state.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @jojeyh but their code threw an error, for me. After reading the docs for [getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), I added `.mediaDevices` and set the constraints

```
var constraints = { audio: true } // add video constraints if required

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then((stream) => {
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    // ... rest of code
})
```

This worked, for me.