# Web audio api - The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

So I've this warning on my console.
I read the documentation : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

I did everything as they said but I still have this warning.
Here's my code :

```
let context;
window.onload = function() {
    context = new AudioContext();
    ...
}

// click event
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.closest('.play1')) {
       context.resume().then(() => {
            source.start(0);
       });
    }
})
```

The warning text is about this line : `context = new AudioContext();`

Does anyone see what I'm missing ? Thank you very much

Comment: onload is not a user generated UI interaction . Common to use a btn 'click' as the user-input event req'd by web-audio AND then to get the new Context and to wire it up to streams and to get permissions per the API docs

Comment: Does it mean I can not load my audio before the click event ? Because the idea was to load my audio inside a BufferSource before the user click to play the song

Comment: You can do whatever you want.  You're only prevented from hearing any audio until you get a user gesture to resume the context or start the buffer source.

Comment: Yes but from my example, I only declare a contexte inside an onload event. So basically I'm not supposed to get this warning no ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome Javascript issue in getting user audio - The AudioContext was not allowed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026293/google-chrome-javascript-issue-in-getting-user-audio-the-audiocontext-was-not)

Answer (score 18):

Yes, the warning is because you did not create the context in a user gesture.  I find the warning quite annoying because it is not wrong to create the context without a user gesture.  What is not allowed is starting/resuming the context without a user gesture.

Since you resume the context with a user click, everything is fine.

I would ignore it.  Or create the context with a click or other user gesture.

I wish Chrome would fix the warning so that it only shows up when you try to resume a context without a user gesture.

Comment: Does it mean I can not load my audio before the click event ? Because the idea was to load my audio inside a BufferSource before the user click to play the song

Comment: You should be able to load audio.  You are only blocked from playing audible sounds until you use a user-gesture to resume a context or to start your AudioBufferSourceNode.  (If you do these without a gesture, it may look like things are working, but they're not and you won't hear anything.)

Comment: firefox does it too.