# AudioContext not allowed to start when I point a domain at the IP

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I'm working on a webgame site, and part of that includes playing audio. I want to host my own server for this site at least to start because I've never done it before and it sounds like a good learning experience for me. I got the site and the game working and I can play the game. Others have also been able to play it without issue using my router's external IP after I set up forwarding etc.

The game includes a soundcloud audio player widget that I made invisible so that I can use my own graphics for buttons. I ran into the problem of not being able to autoplay audio, but fixed it with allow="autoplay" in the iframe containing the widget.

All seemed good until today, when I bought a cheap domain name and set a domain pointer to my IP address. This is through domain.com and the pointer is of type URL Stealth. It sounds like that's the best way to go so that I don't expose my router's external IP address.

Now, however, my site will pull up, but on hitting the play button the console spits out the error saying

```
The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
```

I am of course confused because I can still play the game correctly if I type my IP address and port into the search bar as I have been doing. The only difference that I can see is the domain name. So what is it about this domain pointer that causes my play button to stop working?

I can also confirm that if I do as it asks and make a gesture on the page I can then play the game as normal.

For reference, I'm using chrome and haven't tested on any other browsers.

As usual, I never know what information I've left out of the explanation, so feel free to ask and I'm happy to provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome Javascript issue in getting user audio - The AudioContext was not allowed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026293/google-chrome-javascript-issue-in-getting-user-audio-the-audiocontext-was-not)

Comment: It looks like a great start, but now I'm getting told that getAudioContext() is not defined. It appears to be a function associated with P5.js, which I downloaded and tried to import, and was told that I can't use an import statement outside of a module. This seems like I'm doing something wrong. Any pointers?

Comment: Please put some code in this qus, or in a new qus.